# python check datetime is older then n days?

Tags: python, date, time, difference

I am given a date as string,for example `'2019-10-29T10:31:58.000Z'`.
I want to check if this date and time is older then 5 days from the current date and time.
What is the best way to check this? 
All other related threads I found had a different datetime format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is ISO8601 (with a Z for a zero timezone), so...

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> s = '2019-10-29T10:31:58.000Z'
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(s.rstrip('Z'))
>>> days_since = (datetime.datetime.now() - dt).total_seconds() / 86400.0
>>> print(days_since)
2.1420510361689815  # (at the time of writing)
```